# In JavaScript is it possible in anyway to ignore some parameters in a function call?

Tags: javascript

Like in array destructuring we can do something like this:

```
let [, b] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

so why not `foo(, b)`?

Comment: Typically the "optional" parameters that you might want would appear as the trailing entries so that they can be omitted, i.e. `foo(b)` with the parameters swapped.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is specifically about a syntax/specification choice.

Comment: That would be called an elision, where the first member is elided. But it's not valid syntax, so see user2864740's comment.

Answer (score 5):

You can explicitly pass `undefined` as the first argument to achieve the same thing:

```js
function foo(item1, item2) {
  console.log(item1, item2);
}
foo(undefined, 'b')
```

Also, if the function accepts an array or an object, you can simply pass an array or object with only the properties you want it to contain:

```js
function foo(arr) {
  console.log(arr[0], arr[1]);
}
foo([, 'b']);
```

```js
function foo({ a, b }) {
  console.log(a, b);
}
foo({ b: 'b' });
```

Comment: See also function pass, bind and apply

Comment: Note: the array literal `[, 'b']` is the same as `[undefined, 'b']`.

Comment: @user2864740—not exactly. There is no index 0, so there can't be a value there. `[,1].forEach((value, idx) => console.log(idx+':'+value))` prints `1:1`, not `0:undefined, 1:1`. Most of the array iterating methods do not visit missing or elided elements. But in a call `fn(...[,1])` the *arguments* object will have values `undefined, 1`. ;-)

Comment: Uhg, that got me :}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `arguments` object like this:

```js
function foo() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i] + " ");
  }
}


foo("a", );
```

That way you can use any number of parameters and will not need to defined each and every one in the function, unless required.